# Submitting multiple textareas using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am building a page where a user (teacher) can assing students homework tasks. Depending on how many tasks are assigned, the number of comment boxes will change.
I have a page in which multiple forms are created. The number of textareas vary as described above. All student answers are shown on the same page. A comment box is shown for each individual task, in order to enable the teacher to respond to every type of mistake (if any) the student make.
Each comment field is related to a specific ID (the student answer for that specific task), but how do I most economically go about creating an array and submitting the specific textarea 'on change'. I.e. I want the database comment field to be dynamically updated when a teacher is done commenting on a specific student answer.
I am not a complete novice, but far from being proficient in java (jquery and ajax, which I use to handle most of my site). I use php and MySQL for serverside and jquery for client side data handling.

I have not really begone coding yet as I am looking for a good and viable approach. I have between 30-40 tasks assigned on avarage.

```
<div id="defaultPortlet<?php echo $portL; ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
  <div class="portlet-body clearfix">
    <form>
      <textarea class="col-lg-12" rows="3">
        <?php echo $row_dbResponce['ten_notes']; ?>
      </textarea>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to update the database on change (i.e. usig ajax handle data and calling a php database update page). 
Any help on how to approach this problem would be usefull.

Comment: Can we see your AJAX and other JS?

Comment: Put a `data-answer="ID"` attribute in the `textarea`. Then your AJAX code can send an array of `{ id: $(this).data('answer'), comment: $(this).val() }`.

Comment: @gibsonman507 I do not have any yet, as I am looking for an efficient approach to setting up the comment boxex (e.g. should I create an array or identify them by answer ID etc.), look for changes using jquery, and only sending data for that particular commentbox (textarea).I am trying to do this the right way the first time around, and not complicating it with loops and if statements as I have a tendency to do :-)

Comment: @Barmar cheers, I will work a bit on that and see where it gets me :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
<textarea class="col-lg-12" rows="3">
```

to

```
<textarea class="col-lg-12" rows="3" id="descriptor<?php echo $portL; ?>">
```

Then in your jquery...

```
$("textarea[descriptor^='news']").each(function( index ) {
 $(this).change();
})
```

Comment: Just looked at the each function. This was exactely what I was looking for! Thanks.